# Call Lifecyclecallback of parent entity when child entity is updated

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I have two entities with a oneToMany/ManyToOne relation inside my doctrine project. Both of them have a lifecyclecallback function to calculate different properties. For example the first entity **ShoppingCart** has an aggregate field: `totalArticlePrice` which calculates the total price of all articles:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\PostUpdate
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 * @ORM\PostLoad
 */
 public function lifecycle(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void {
        
   /** Total price */
   foreach($this->articles as $article) {
     $this->totalArticlePrice += $article->getPriceTotal();
   }
 }
```

Inside my Angular Application i have created an ShoppingCart which can have multiple articles (This just works fine!) Below all articles there is a field which lists the total price of all articles : `totalArticlePrice`.

The Problem is that total price doesnt get updated when i add a new Article. But if i refresh the page the total price is correct. So i need a way to tell my entities that if one of them is updated the other one should update aswell to get both data at the same time. Reloading the page after adding a new article is not really a solution to show the total amount.

Everything works fine except for this, so just need a way to update an entity when an other entity is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you just created a lifecycle event for articles and trigger the total price calculation for the ShoppingCart in there. I would also recommend to move the totalPrice logic to another method that just gets called by the lifecycle() one so that you could manually trigger it without causing problems in the future (like other stuff you might want to do when those events are triggered).

I assume that, at the moment, the price is correct after the refresh because of the PostLoad event that doesn't get triggered on the "add article" route because the ShoppingCart is already in the entity manager. You could trigger it by using "refresh" on the ShoppingCart after the article is added (assuming that it's not a generated route by API Platform or something).